# Angular 1.6 component binding

Tags: data-binding, components, angular1.6

Thank you for watching my question.

So, I have an angular 1.6 component in 2 places, and when I change a variable on one of them I want to be changed in the second also.

Do you have an idea how can I accomplish that?

Regards,
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use service to share data.
Or you can broadcast events through $rootScope and send your data as a payload of these events.

Comment: Thank you man, I used a service, the problem was that I used uib-modal and because components wasn't in the same controller I needed to use this service to synchronize the data.